# I think I have some reusable code, but I do not know how to handle it

Tags: jquery

How do I handle this because the same `variable` is used a lot in code

```
function contentsFade() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.inner__section__contents').each(function () {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 100;
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            } else if (bottom_of_window < bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });

        $('.photo__contents').each(function () {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 100;
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).addClass('active');

            } else if (bottom_of_window < bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- How many `variables` can be reused?
- what could be better way to make this code more simple and multi time
  reusable according to situation?

Comment: You can reuse any variables as any amount of times as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only difference is between `+ 100` and `- 100`, so you can use a function that you pass a boolean variable that sets whether you add or subtract:

```
const checkActive = (add) => function() {
  var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
  var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + (add ? 100 : -100);
  //                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else if (bottom_of_window < bottom_of_object) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
};

$('.inner__section__contents').each(checkActive(true)); // add 100
$('.photo__contents').each(checkActive(false)); // subtract 100
```

Note that `checkActive` is a function that *returns a function* (and the returned function is passed as the callback to `.each`)

Also note that, given your current logic, it's possible for `checkActive` to do *nothing at all*, in case `bottom_of_window === bottom_of_object`. You might consider using `>=` or `<=` for one of those comparisons.